# transferring eventhandlers between objects in C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, event-handling

I'm searched around a bit and am surprised that I haven't found a more simple answer.  I'm following a simply MVVM model and have a view models ("parentVM") that holds another view model ("childVM") as a field exposed by a public property (get/set).  The problem i'm having is i'm trying to subscribe to the child view models's propertychanged event in the parent's initializer.  But when a new childVM is set the event handlers are lost.

```
public parentVM : INotitifyPropertyChange{
    private _childVM = new childVM();

    public parentVM(){
        _childVM.PropertyChanged += someHandler;
    }


    public childVM {
         get{
             return _childVM;
         }
         set{
             _childVM = value;
             //EVENTHANDLERS ARE NOW GONE
         }
    }
    ....
}
```

Is there any way to transfer the existing event handler to the new object?

This is a simplified example. I know that i could simply move the line:

```
_childVM.PropertyChange += someHandler;
```

but this won't work for external object that subscribe to the event.  In those cases you are unlikely to know what the object is and what the handler is.

Perhaps there is a workaround by referencing a List internally changing from the += eventHandler to a more manual AddHander method, that then populates the List for future reference.  Dunno just thinking outload at this point.

P.S. if there is a syntactical error in the example, please forgive, i don't have intellisense and this isn't real code... just trying to convey the point.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.  VM property changes are implicitly handled by the view if done correctly.  You shouldn't necessarily need an explicit event handler for them. Can you give some context for what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider not creating a new instance of `childVM` at all, merely updating it's internal model.

However, assuming you do not want this, the code below should do what you describe. Note that it also removes the event handlers from the original `ChildVM` (I used more standard capitalization in my code). Failure to remove event handlers often leads to memory leaks.

```
class ParentVM
{
    private ChildVM _childVM = new ChildVM();

    public ParentVM()
    {
        _childVM.PropertyChanged += SomeHandler;
    }

    public ChildVM ChildVM
    {
        get
        {
            return _childVM;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var handler in _childVM.GetPropertyChangedHandlers())
            {
                _childVM.PropertyChanged -= handler;
                value.PropertyChanged += handler;
            }

            _childVM = value;
        }
    }

    private void SomeHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you will need this extra method `GetPropertyChangedHandlers` in your child view model class, because you cannot call [`GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) from outside the type that defines the event. Here's the code for the `ChildVM`:

```
class ChildVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PropertyChangedEventHandler[] GetPropertyChangedHandlers()
    {
        return PropertyChanged.GetInvocationList().
               OfType<PropertyChangedEventHandler>().ToArray();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Back to alternative solutions: are you sure it is necessary to account for external code subscribing to these events? If you're doing simple data binding, you should just raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `ChildVM` property when it is set, which should take care of your problem without all this extra code.

Comment: thanks!  yeah i'm using the propertyChanged as merely an example. my true use case a bit more complex than databinding.

Comment: You could still decouple events with EventAggregator

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to move to EventAggregator?

There are lots of them around, e.g. in Prism and caliburn.micro.

The basic idea is:
There are entities that Publish events and entities that subscribe to events (i.e. handle them).
So you move from direct subscribing (+=) to a more loosly coupled architecture,
as you publish your events only to the EventAggregator and it handles where it
should call the handlers for those events (the multicast delegate as before the +=)

It is really very easy and you do no longer have this dependency in your code.

Please have a look at the following links

[MSDN Prism description of EventAggregator (very good)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

[caliburn.micro description of EventAggregator](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator)

Answer (score 1):

**Better Answer:**

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your ParentVM.  Raise the event when you change ChildVM.  Your external objects subscribing to ChildVM events can subscribe to ParentVMs property changed event and can update their event handlers on ChildVM when they are notified that it changed.

**Original Answer:**
I would create two methods `SubscribeChildVMEvents(ChildVM)` and `UnsubscribeChildVMEvent(ChildVM)` and do this in your setter:

```
set{
  UnsubscribeChildVMEvents(_childVM);
             _childVM = value;
  SubscribeChildVMEvents(_childVM);
             //EVENTHANDLERS ARE NOW NOT GONE
         }
```

It is good practice to remove event handlers from objects.

Comment: This does not deal with external code also subscribing to those events. The question is if that is actually necessary.

Comment: Perhaps you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the ParentVM and raise the `PropertyChanged` event after changing the ChildVM, so that the external code can listen for that event and be prompted to re-subscribe to the new ChildVM.

Comment: That would make most sense to me as well.